# (API MANAGER) Proxy API calls to backend service

Tags: java, class, wso2, wso2-api-manager, interceptor

I need to write interceptor java class that intercepts all API calls on AM and proxy to my backend 
service to do further check with user's parameters on my local db. To do so I need to write a custom 
handler class and include it in /repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml 
file. For sure I'm doing something wrong, because when I test API call from postman it returns only 
the same API parameters, not calling at all backend service. Can someone help me with this?

java class that I included in AM as jar file..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.rest.AbstractHandler;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;


public class CustomAPIProxyHandler extends AbstractHandler {

 public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {

  if (messageContext != null) {
   ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
   HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8085/drm/checkKpi");
   String jsonStr = obj.writeValueAsString(messageContext);
   StringEntity js = new StringEntity(jsonStr);
   post.setEntity(js);
   post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

  }
  return false;
 }

 public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) {
  return true;
 }

}
```

This is pom.xml that I used to generate jar file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- 
v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.test</artifactId>
   <packaging>bundle</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>org.wso2.carbon.test.authenticator</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>wso2-nexus</id>
         <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
         </releases>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>wso2.releases</id>
         <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
         </releases>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>wso2.snapshots</id>
         <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
         </snapshots>
         <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </releases>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>wso2.releases</id>
         <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
         </releases>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>wso2.snapshots</id>
         <name>WSO2 Snapshot Repository</name>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
         </snapshots>
         <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </releases>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>wso2-nexus</id>
         <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
         </releases>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.7</source>
               <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
               <instructions>
                  <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.wso2.carbon.test</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                  <Bundle-Name>org.wso2.carbon.test</Bundle-Name>
                  <Export-Package>org.wso2.carbon.test.*,</Export-Package>
                  <Import-Package>*; resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
               </instructions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
         <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7-wso2v10</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
         <artifactId>synapse-commons</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7-wso2v10</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway</artifactId>
         <version>6.1.66</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is how I included class jar in /repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handlers xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomAPIProxyHandler" />
   #foreach($handler in $handlers)
   <handler class="$handler.className">
      #if($handler.hasProperties())
    #set ($map = $handler.getProperties() )
    #foreach($property in $map.entrySet())
      <property name="$!property.key" value="$!property.value" />
      #end
    #end
   </handler>
   #end
    #end
</handlers>
```

I tested that class with java project and it works, with AM it doesn't, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you see any errors? When I try to run your handler implementation, I got a ClassNotFound exception for org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.

Also, where is your jar is deployed?

Comment: In handler class i needed to surround a few parameters with multiple try/catch, that I eliminated before I posted in the question. Try this:

Comment: String jsonStr = null;
  try {jsonStr = obj.writeValueAsString(messageContext);
  } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
  }    
     StringEntity js;
  try {
   js = new StringEntity(jsonStr);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }     
     post.setEntity(js);
     post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     
     try {
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

    }
    return false;
   }

Comment: @Menaka tested everything with localhost, I didn't deploy it on server. Have you already worked with interceptor class in AM? If you have any suggestion you are welcome :)

Comment: @Menaka if you can't see ObjectMapper class you are missing a library in pom.xml

Comment: You have to deploy the handler jar in <AM_HOME>/repository/components/dropins directory.

Comment: @Menaka I put that jar in <AM_HOME>/repository/components/dropins directory, but in my local workspace, not on server

Comment: After applying it did you restart the server? while restarting did you notice any errors?

Comment: Does local workspace mean in your local WSO2 API Manager node? (gateway?)

Comment: @NadeePoornima yes i did restart the server every time I made some changes. The problem is that the AM is not even reading my interceptor class, I know that because of log messages that I inserted in the class, I don't see any change.

Comment: @Menaka yes, I mean in my local wso2 am node. I installed wso2 am on my pc, so I work locally with AM folders thats on my pc.

Comment: In your api configuration file, <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--api_name.xml file, can you able see your handler config applied?

Comment: @Menaka I resolved my problem with reading interceptor class in am, you were right I also get this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, I will try to find the solution for this

Comment: @Menaka the problem was that I didn't include in velocity.xml under PROTOTYPE handler my interceptor class, as though I published it locally

Comment: @Menaka I resolved the problem with class not found for ObjectMapper importing another library com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, but I still dont know where to catch the body of the object that Im sending with postman in messageContext I see only these 3 things: MessageID : urn:uuid:3a3d9ec0-46c8-4038-8d7a-e825ed937e8e, Headers : /, Body : <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>. Is there any way to read the body of the actual http message?

Comment: In order to read the message content, you have to build the message. 

org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
RelayUtils.buildMessage(axis2MessageContext);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208263/discussion-between-menaka-and-nina-lukic).